# What are the originals of the poems Tagore has translated from English into Bengali?

Tags: poetry, translation, bengali-language, rabindranath-tagore

Rabindranath Tagore's 1886 collection of verse *[কড়ি ও কোমল](https://archive.org/details/KariOKomal/mode/1up) / ka.Di o komal*, "Sharps and Flats", includes a set of 15 or so poems under the general heading *[বিদেশী ফূলের গুচ্ছ](https://archive.org/details/KariOKomal/page/n58/mode/1up) / videshii phuuler guchchha*, "A Bouquet of Foreign Flowers". The poems lack titles. Instead, each is preceded by the name of a poet from whom Tagore is translating: "Shelley", "Mrs Browning", "Ernest Myers", etc.

Some of the poems are well-known enough that the translation rings a bell. For example, the first poem, marked "Shelley", begins:

> মধুর সূর্জ্যর আলো, আকাশ বিমল,
> সঘনে উঠিছে নাচি তরঙ্গ উজ্জ্বল।
>      মধ্যান্হের স্বচ্ছ করে
>      সাজিয়াছে থরে থরে
> ক্ষুদ্র নীল দ্বীপগুলী, শুভ্র-শৈল-শির

> madhur suurjyer aalo, aakaash vimal
> saghane uThichhe naachi tara~Nga ujjwal.
>      madhyaanher svachchha kare
>      saajiyaachhe thare thare
> kShudra niil dviipagulii, shubhra-shail-shira

> Soft sunlight, a clear sky
> Dancing, bright waves have oft risen.
>      In midday's clean hands
>      have been arranged, layer by layer
> tiny blue islands, and white, rocky summits

This is recognizably Shelley's "[Stanzas Written in Dejection, near Naples](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/45140/stanzas-written-in-dejection-near-naples)":

> The sun is warm, the sky is clear,
>           The waves are dancing fast and bright,
>      Blue isles and snowy mountains wear
>      The purple noon's transparent might

Likewise, the poem headed "Mrs Browning" that begins "ওই আদরের নামে ডেকো সখা মোরে / oi aadarer naame Deko sakhaa more", "Call me by that pet name, my love" is obviously [Sonnet 33](https://internetpoem.com/elizabeth-barrett-browning/sonnet-33-yes-call-m-poem/) from *Sonnets from the Portuguese*: "Yes, call me by my pet name!"

However, throughout the series, the lack of titles and the absence of any information about which specific poem is being translated makes it difficult to identify the originals from which Tagore is translating. Some of the poets, too, have faded into (relative) obscurity. It is unlikely that a mention of "Moore" or "Hood" or "Augusta Webster" will bring any of their poems immediately to mind, even to an English major.

Further, some of the poems Tagore translates were themselves not originally in English. For example, Tagore includes a translation from Victor Hugo, presumably working from an English translation of Hugo's French original. And the last poem, or subset of poems, is headed "কোন জাপানী কবিতার ইংগ্রাজী অনুবাদ হইতে / kon jaapaanii kavitaar i.ngraajii anuvaad haite", "From the English translation of some Japanese poems". No information is given about which poets or translations Tagore is referencing.

The poems in *[বিদেশী ফূলের গুচ্ছ](https://archive.org/details/KariOKomal/page/n58/mode/1up) / videshii phuuler guchchha* read well enough in Bengali, but the absence of specific information about the originals is frustrating. Is there any source that provides comprehensive information about which English poems Tagore was translating? For the poems that themselves had been translated into English from another language, is there any information about what the originals were, and which English translations Tagore was using?

**Notes**:

1. The usual disclaimer applies: All translations from the Bengali are my own, and my Bengali is pitiful, so rely on them AYOR
2. Transliterations from Bengali follow the [iTrans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITRANS) schema.

Comment: I found one of them, using Google translate. The original of the [Swinburne](https://bn.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A6%AA%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A4%E0%A6%BE:%E0%A6%95%E0%A6%A1%E0%A6%BC%E0%A6%BF_%E0%A6%93_%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%B2-%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%AC%E0%A7%80%E0%A6%A8%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%A6%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%A8%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A5_%E0%A6%A0%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%81%E0%A6%B0.djvu/%E0%A7%AD%E0%A7%AC) is [*A Ballad of Dreamland*](https://poets.org/poem/ballad-dreamland).

Comment: That's great! How did you copy-paste the Bengali text into Google Translate? I found that I couldn't copy from the source texts and had to type out all the Bengali. (Not necessarily for Google Translate, just to cite the source in this answer, for example)

Comment: The [Wikisource](https://bn.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A6%AA%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A4%E0%A6%BE:%E0%A6%95%E0%A6%A1%E0%A6%BC%E0%A6%BF_%E0%A6%93_%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%B2-%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%AC%E0%A7%80%E0%A6%A8%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%A6%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%A8%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A5_%E0%A6%A0%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%81%E0%A6%B0.djvu/%E0%A7%AD%E0%A7%AC) for Tagore's poem has the Bengali in copy-and-paste form on the left page (and a replica of the original publication on the right page). The hard part was choosing the words from Google's translation of Tagore's translation to search for in the original poem.

Comment: ah. Thanks! Surprisingly, [TagoreWeb](http://www.tagoreweb.in) doesn't appear to even have these translations up on their site, as far as I could tell. I looked because I have been copy/pasting from there, and ended up having to just retype. Which, given how pathetic my Bengali is, was quite tedious.

Comment: Yeah, I can read the Bengali but I recognized only a couple of the original poems. Because Tagore uses the originals as springboards for creating essentially new poems in Bengali—they're rhymed, for example—the translations don't correspond super closely to the originals.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116588/discussion-between-verbose-and-peter-shor).

Comment: And the [Moore](https://bn.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A6%AA%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A4%E0%A6%BE:%E0%A6%95%E0%A6%A1%E0%A6%BC%E0%A6%BF_%E0%A6%93_%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%B2-%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%AC%E0%A7%80%E0%A6%A8%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%A6%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%A8%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A5_%E0%A6%A0%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%81%E0%A6%B0.djvu/%E0%A7%AD%E0%A7%A8) turned out to be easy, once I identified the poet.  One of Thomas Moore's most famous poems/songs is [*The Last Rose of Summer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Rose_of_Summer), and this is the one Tagore translated.

Comment: And the [other Christina Rossetti poem](https://bn.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A6%AA%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A4%E0%A6%BE:%E0%A6%95%E0%A6%A1%E0%A6%BC%E0%A6%BF_%E0%A6%93_%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%B2-%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%AC%E0%A7%80%E0%A6%A8%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%A6%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%A8%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A5_%E0%A6%A0%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%81%E0%A6%B0.djvu/%E0%A7%AD%E0%A7%AB) is [May](https://www.poemhunter.com/poem/may/). I found it after I realized that  I should search Christina Rossetti's poems for "April" and "May" (I had been searching for "spring").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to identify many of the poems, using Google and Bing translate and searching for keywords these gave me. Using Google books, I further identified two anthologies which contain several of these poems. By looking in these anthologies, I was fairly easily able to identify some of the poems by lesser-known poets.

The first anthology is: [Latter-Day Lyrics](https://archive.org/details/latter-daylyrics00kohlrich) (1878), edited by W. Davenport Adams.

This book contains the poems:

- [*A Sigh in the Morning Gray,*](https://archive.org/details/latter-daylyrics00kohlrich/page/38/mode/2up) by Aubrey de Vere ([Here in Tagore](https://bn.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A6%AA%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A4%E0%A6%BE:%E0%A6%95%E0%A6%A1%E0%A6%BC%E0%A6%BF_%E0%A6%93_%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%B2-%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%AC%E0%A7%80%E0%A6%A8%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%A6%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%A8%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A5_%E0%A6%A0%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%81%E0%A6%B0.djvu/%E0%A7%AC%E0%A7%AC))
- [*After*](https://archive.org/details/latter-daylyrics00kohlrich/page/214/mode/2up) by Philip Bourke Marston, ([Here](https://bn.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A6%AA%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A4%E0%A6%BE:%E0%A6%95%E0%A6%A1%E0%A6%BC%E0%A6%BF_%E0%A6%93_%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%B2-%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%AC%E0%A7%80%E0%A6%A8%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%A6%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%A8%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A5_%E0%A6%A0%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%81%E0%A6%B0.djvu/%E0%A7%AC%E0%A7%AF) in Tagore)
- [*Stay Me No More*,](https://archive.org/details/latter-daylyrics00kohlrich/page/38/mode/2up) by Ernest Myers. ([Here in Tagore](https://bn.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A6%AA%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A4%E0%A6%BE:%E0%A6%95%E0%A6%A1%E0%A6%BC%E0%A6%BF_%E0%A6%93_%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%B2-%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%AC%E0%A7%80%E0%A6%A8%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%A6%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%A8%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A5_%E0%A6%A0%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%81%E0%A6%B0.djvu/%E0%A7%AC%E0%A7%AB))
  [Note: Later, Myers revised this poem, giving it the title *Arousal*, replacing *Love* with *Ease*, and adding a third verse.]
- [*Not To Be*](https://archive.org/details/latter-daylyrics00kohlrich/page/176/mode/2up), by Augusta Webster ([Here in Tagore](https://bn.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A6%AA%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A4%E0%A6%BE:%E0%A6%95%E0%A6%A1%E0%A6%BC%E0%A6%BF_%E0%A6%93_%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%B2-%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%AC%E0%A7%80%E0%A6%A8%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%A6%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%A8%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A5_%E0%A6%A0%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%81%E0%A6%B0.djvu/%E0%A7%AC%E0%A7%AD))
- [*Too Soon So Fair, Fair Lilies*](https://archive.org/details/latter-daylyrics00kohlrich/page/178/mode/2up) by Augusta Webster ([Here](https://bn.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A6%AA%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A4%E0%A6%BE:%E0%A6%95%E0%A6%A1%E0%A6%BC%E0%A6%BF_%E0%A6%93_%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%B2-%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%AC%E0%A7%80%E0%A6%A8%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%A6%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%A8%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A5_%E0%A6%A0%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%81%E0%A6%B0.djvu/%E0%A7%AC%E0%A7%AE) in Tagore)
  [Tagore dropped half of the verses of this poem, but translated the rest reasonably faithfully.]

The other anthology is
[The Poets and Poetry of England in the Nineteenth Century](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Poets_and_Poetry_of_England/mQRAAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=rufus%20w%20griswold%20stoddard), edited by Rufus W. Griswold (1875).

This book contains the poems:

- [*Stanzas Written in Dejection, Near Naples*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Poets_and_Poetry_of_England/mQRAAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=written%20in%20dejection) by Percy Bysshe Shelley ([Here in Tagore](https://bn.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A6%AA%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A4%E0%A6%BE:%E0%A6%95%E0%A6%A1%E0%A6%BC%E0%A6%BF_%E0%A6%93_%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%B2-%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%AC%E0%A7%80%E0%A6%A8%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%A6%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%A8%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A5_%E0%A6%A0%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%81%E0%A6%B0.djvu/%E0%A7%AB%E0%A7%AF))
- [*May*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Poets_and_Poetry_of_England/mQRAAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22As%20yet%20the%20poppies%20were%20not%20born%22) by Christina Rossetti ([Here](https://bn.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A6%AA%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A4%E0%A6%BE:%E0%A6%95%E0%A6%A1%E0%A6%BC%E0%A6%BF_%E0%A6%93_%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%B2-%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%AC%E0%A7%80%E0%A6%A8%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%A6%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%A8%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A5_%E0%A6%A0%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%81%E0%A6%B0.djvu/%E0%A7%AD%E0%A7%AB) in Tagore)
- [*Death*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Poets_and_Poetry_of_England/mQRAAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22%20that%20now%20reply%20In%20sunlight%20to%20the%20sun%22) by Thomas Hood ([Here](https://bn.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A6%AA%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A4%E0%A6%BE:%E0%A6%95%E0%A6%A1%E0%A6%BC%E0%A6%BF_%E0%A6%93_%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%B2-%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%AC%E0%A7%80%E0%A6%A8%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%A6%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%A8%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A5_%E0%A6%A0%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%81%E0%A6%B0.djvu/%E0%A7%AE%E0%A7%A6) in Tagore)

The other poems are:

- [*Irreparableness*](https://allpoetry.com/Irreparableness), by Elizabeth Barrett Browning ([Here in Tagore](https://bn.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A6%AA%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A4%E0%A6%BE:%E0%A6%95%E0%A6%A1%E0%A6%BC%E0%A6%BF_%E0%A6%93_%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%B2-%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%AC%E0%A7%80%E0%A6%A8%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%A6%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%A8%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A5_%E0%A6%A0%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%81%E0%A6%B0.djvu/%E0%A7%AC%E0%A7%A9))
- [*The Last Rose of Summer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Rose_of_Summer) by Thomas Moore, ([Here](https://bn.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A6%AA%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A4%E0%A6%BE:%E0%A6%95%E0%A6%A1%E0%A6%BC%E0%A6%BF_%E0%A6%93_%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%B2-%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%AC%E0%A7%80%E0%A6%A8%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%A6%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%A8%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A5_%E0%A6%A0%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%81%E0%A6%B0.djvu/%E0%A7%AD%E0%A7%A8) in Tagore)
- [*A Ballad of Dreamland*](https://poets.org/poem/ballad-dreamland) by Swinburne ([Here](https://bn.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A6%AA%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A4%E0%A6%BE:%E0%A6%95%E0%A6%A1%E0%A6%BC%E0%A6%BF_%E0%A6%93_%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%B2-%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%AC%E0%A7%80%E0%A6%A8%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%A6%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%A8%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A5_%E0%A6%A0%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%81%E0%A6%B0.djvu/%E0%A7%AD%E0%A7%AC) in Tagore)
- [*Mirage*](https://www.poemhunter.com/poem/mirage/) by Christina Rossetti ([Here](https://bn.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A6%AA%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A4%E0%A6%BE:%E0%A6%95%E0%A6%A1%E0%A6%BC%E0%A6%BF_%E0%A6%93_%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%B2-%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%AC%E0%A7%80%E0%A6%A8%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%A6%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%A8%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A5_%E0%A6%A0%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%81%E0%A6%B0.djvu/%E0%A7%AD%E0%A7%AE) in Tagore)
- [*Épitaphe*](https://www.speakerty.com/victor-hugo/les-contemplations/epitaphe/) by Victor Hugo
  ([Here](https://bn.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A6%AA%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A4%E0%A6%BE:%E0%A6%95%E0%A6%A1%E0%A6%BC%E0%A6%BF_%E0%A6%93_%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%B2-%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%AC%E0%A7%80%E0%A6%A8%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%A6%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%A8%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A5_%E0%A6%A0%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%81%E0%A6%B0.djvu/%E0%A7%AD%E0%A7%A7) in Tagore)
- [*The Flown Bird*](https://archive.org/details/Httpbooks.google.com.aubooksidD6_PAAAAMAAJ/page/n899/mode/2up?q=flown+bird) by Richard Henry Stoddard ([Here](https://bn.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A6%AA%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A4%E0%A6%BE:%E0%A6%95%E0%A6%A1%E0%A6%BC%E0%A6%BF_%E0%A6%93_%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%B2-%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%AC%E0%A7%80%E0%A6%A8%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%A6%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%A8%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A5_%E0%A6%A0%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%81%E0%A6%B0.djvu/%E0%A7%AE%E0%A7%A7) in Tagore)
  [Tagore translates the first three of the four verses]

There is more on the last two poems below:

@verbose identified the poem *Épitaphe*. There are two 19th-century English translations of this poem, by [Henry Carrington](https://archive.org/details/translationsfrom00hugo/page/130/mode/2up) and by [Nelson Rich Tyreman](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Child_fantasy_and_Other_Poems/688IAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22he+lived+and+ever+played%22&pg=PA57-IA1&printsec=frontcover), but it appears that Tagore translated it directly from the French. [This blog post](https://thespace.ink/literature-and-fiction/letters-essays/rabindranath-tagore-and-french/) confirms that Tagore knew French, and that he translated at least four other poems by Victor Hugo.

You can also see that Tagore translated the poem directly from the French by looking at the translations themselves. Tagore translates some aspects of the poem more faithfully than either of the two other translators. For the Tyreman translation, in the first two lines, both Tagore and Hugo use words for *laughing* and *Nature*, while Tyreman replaces these by *smiling* and *Earth*. And for the Carrington translation, Hugo writes "birds painted a thousand colors" and Tagore writes "hundred-colored birds," while Carrington just says "myriad birds" without mentioning their colors.

Tagore's title for the last poem is translated by Google as *(From an English translation of a Japanese poem)*.
However, despite Tagore's title, this is not an actual translation of a Japanese poem into English, but an Japanese-inspired English poem, although if Tagore saw it in its first appearance in *Scribners Monthly* in 1876 (linked above), it is entirely understandable that he thought it was a translation from the Japanese. In *Scribner,* the poem is titled

> THE FLOWN BIRD
>   ᴀ ᴊᴀᴘᴀɴᴇsᴇ sᴏɴɢ

and has no author information indicated on the page that contains it (the author is indeed credited in the table of contents).

However, as [*Scribner's Monthly*](https://books.google.com/books?id=RsxZAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA564&lpg=PA564&dq=%22the+article+in+Leisure+Hours+closes+with+the+poem%22&source=bl&ots=gl4TvPhSLe&sig=ACfU3U00XyB1Es5d1jZz25gXnDxYFHKhfw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjBwZOGwdf-AhU8jIkEHZVwBxUQ6AF6BAgIEAM#v=onepage&q=%22the%20article%20in%20Leisure%20Hours%20closes%20with%20the%20poem%22&f=false) explains in 1877:

> The article in “Leisure Hours” closes with the poem published by Mr. Stoddard in *Scribner* for October, 1876, and entitled “The Flown Bird”. This is called by Mr. Mossman a “translation." The beautiful refrain “I have forgotten to forget" is Japanese, and so is most of the imagery, but the story is the poet's own.

This poem was republished in *The Poems of Richard Henry Stoddard* in 1880 with no associated mention of Japan, confirming that it is an original poem.

Comment: A footnote to this answer: Thomas Hardy remarks on the Ernest Myer poem in his [literary notebooks.](https://books.google.com/books?id=SGBaCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA186&lpg=PA186&dq=%22middle-aged+muse%22+hardy&source=bl&ots=EU-ztgHjxX&sig=ACfU3U3xZADrYG8wFQl5p-NHasDQoYMsEQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi8-J6T67LxAhV_TDABHdAlA-IQ6AEwAHoECAQQAw#v=onepage&q=%22middle-aged%20muse%22%20hardy&f=false) He says he liked it when it first was published in 1877, that "Love" was replaced by "Ease" in a revised version (which he seems to have liked less), and that this seems characteristic of the "middle-aged Muse".

Comment: The Victor Hugo poem is [Épitaphe](https://www.speakerty.com/victor-hugo/les-contemplations/epitaphe/). Tagore probably translated this 1843 poem from the [English version by Henry Carrington](https://archive.org/details/translationsfrom00hugo/page/130/mode/2up), published in 1885. Care to edit your answer to include this?

Comment: "Too Soon Fair Lilies" is correct; Tagore has dropped about half the poem, but the remaining lines are exact matches.

Comment: @verbose: great find for the Victor Hugo poem! There actually seem to be two 19th century translations of *Épitaphe* in English, one by Henry Carrington and the other by [Nelson Rich Tyreman](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Child_fantasy_and_Other_Poems/688IAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22he+lived+and+ever+played%22&pg=PA57-IA1&printsec=frontcover). The interesting thing is that for each of these poems, Tagore's translation is closer to Hugo in at least one respect, which makes me suspect that Tagore translated directly from the French. I'll add to my answer when I have the time.

Comment: @verbose: And Googling, I find this webpage which confirms that Tagore knew French, and which seems to indicate that Tagore may have translated at least three of Hugo's poems (although I might be misinterpreting it; it would help to know Bengali — are those three Bengali phrases the names of translated poems?)

Comment: Could you provide a link to the website that says Tagore knew French?

Comment: Oops. I thought I included it, but I see I didn't. [Here it is](https://thespace.ink/literature-and-fiction/letters-essays/rabindranath-tagore-and-french/).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145733/discussion-between-verbose-and-peter-shor).

Comment: @verbose: Let me thank you for asking this question, because searching through Christina Rosetti's poems, I found the poem [*Memory*](https://genius.com/Christina-rossetti-memory-annotated), which is now one of my favorites. One common interpretation of *Memory* is that the subject is unrequited love, but I don't believe it; I think the subject is requited love which is impermissible because of societal constraints — in this case, almost certainly lesbianism, but the poem would work equally well if it were forbidden because of religion or caste. Maybe I should ask a question about it.

Comment: Hey it's fantastic that you found the Japanese poem too! Thanks for all the hard work you put in on this answer, and I'm glad the question was fruitful for you.