# What are the Bengali original texts of the poems which Tagore has translated in Stray birds?

Tags: poetry, translation, rabindranath-tagore, bengali-language

I have been reading [Stray birds](https://www.ibiblio.org/eldritch/rt/stray.htm) by Tagore.
[This link](https://niyogibooksindia.com/books/stray-birds) says that some poems in there are translations of the poems in [Kanika](https://tagoreweb.in/Verses/kanika-31). Do any records exist which maps the English verses to the original bengali poems?

I found one:

> "WHAT language is thine, O sea?"
>     "The language of eternal question."
> "What language is thy answer, O sky?
>     "The language of eternal silence."

is a line for line translation of [প্রশ্নের অতীত](https://archive.org/details/KanikaRabindranathTagore/page/n101/mode/2up) (*prashner atiit*, "The Eternal Question"):

> 'হে সমুদ্র, চিরকাল কী তোমার ভাষা ।'
> সমুদ্র কহিল, 'মোর অনন্ত জিজ্ঞাসা ।'
> 'কিসের স্তব্ধতা তব ওগো গিরিবর ।'
> হিমাদ্রি কহিল, 'মোর চির-নিরুত্তর ।'

> *"he samudra, chirakaal kii tomaar bhaaShaa"
>
> samudra kahila, "mor ananta ji~Naasaa"
>
> "kiser stabhdataa taba ogo girivar"
>
> himaadri kahila, "mor chira-niruttar"*

Source: *Kanika* by Rabindranath Tagore. 1899. Calcutta: Vishwabharati, 1948. Retrieved from [the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/KanikaRabindranathTagore/mode/2up), 11 September 2023.

Comment: Related (converse): [What are the originals of the poems Tagore has translated from English into Bengali?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/16425/17)

Answer (score 2):

Whether the pieces in *[Stray Birds](https://www.ibiblio.org/eldritch/rt/stray.htm)* (1916) can rightly be called poems is debatable. There are indeed a couple of (very) brief poems, such as the one cited in the question. But four lines is as long as they get. Most of *Stray Birds* consists of aphorisms a single line long. Some are indeed quite arresting:

> What is this unseen flame of darkness whose sparks are the stars? (81)
>
> "I have lost my dewdrop," cries the flower to the morning sky that has lost all its stars. (199)

But the vast majority, alas, are trite:

> That love can ever lose is a fact that we cannot accept as truth. (312)
>
> Men are cruel, but Man is kind. (219)
>
> The false can never grow into truth by growing in power. (258)

Yes, some of the jottings in *Stray Birds* are paraphrases of poems from Tagore's 1899 collection of short verses, *kaNikaa* ("Particles"). But his inexplicable decision to reduce those already-brief poems to a single line or two robs the pieces of their power and wit. For example, here is *kaNikaa* 34, [কুটুম্বিতা-বিচার](https://archive.org/details/KanikaRabindranathTagore/page/n55/mode/2up) (*kuTumbitaa-bichaar*, "Family Feeling"):

> কেরোসিন-শিখা বলে মাটির প্রদীপে,
> "ভাই ব'লে ডাক যদি দেব গলা টিপে ।"
> হেনকালে গগনেতে উঠিলেন চাঁদা ;
> কেরোসিন বলি উঠে, "এসো মোর দাদা ।"

[iTrans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITRANS):

> kerosiin-shikha bale maaTir pradiipe,
> "bhaaii ba'le Daaka yadi deba galaa Tipe."
> henakaale gaganete uThilen chaa.Ndaa ;
> kerosiin bali uThe, eso mor daadaa."

Translation (mine):

> The kerosene lantern says to the earthen lamp,
> "If you call me sibling, I'll throttle you."
> Just then the moon rose in the sky—
> The kerosene called out, "Welcome, my elder brother!"

Translation ("Kinship-consciousness", by [William Radice](https://archive.org/details/particlesjotting0000tago/page/48/mode/2up)):

> The kerosene-lantern says to the taper,
> "I'll wring your neck if you say we're kin."
> Whereas to the moon he says, "Come in:
> I welcome you warmly as my brother."

Tagore's rendition ("Stray Birds" 53):

> While the glass lamp rebukes the earthen for calling it cousin, the moon rises, and the glass lamp, with a bland smile, calls her, "My dear, dear sister."

This is extremely weak sauce. A *glass lamp* could be quite pretty, after all, whereas a *kerosene lantern* is stained and smelly. Part of the force of the original is that a clay lamp is in fact more appealing, visually and aromatically, than a kerosene lantern. A *rebuke* is several degrees of temperature lower than a threat to wring the neck. And of course, translation cannot capture the cultural nuances of the kinship words "bhaaii" (which could mean brother, cousin, or simply friend) and "daadaa" (which specifically is an honorific for one's elder brother, or for any older personage accorded that status). The contrast between "bhaaii", a fairly innocuous address to someone seen as an equal, and "daadaa", a hierarchical if potentially affectionate term, underscores the difference between the kerosene lantern's gruff threat to the earthen lamp and the obsequiousness of its address to the moon. That they both literally mean "brother" make the poem laugh-out-loud funny, particularly as Tagore defers the word "daadaa" to the very end, making it the punchline.

Even a translator as skilled as Radice does not fully convey the wit and power of Tagore's original; but Tagore's own inept foray is lamentable indeed. It is an act of service, therefore, to redirect readers of *Stray Birds* to the corresponding poems in *kaNikaa*, so here is a table of the 30 such correspondences that I have found.

| *Stray Birds* number | *kaNikaa* number | *kaNikaa* title | Transliteration | Literal Translation | Radice Translation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 77 | ধ্রুবাণি তস্য নশ্যন্তি | dhruvaaNi tasya nasyanti | The imperishable too is destroyed (Sanskrit) | Pointless Grief |
| 12 | 81 | প্রশ্নের অতীত | prashner atiit | The Original Question | Beyond All Questioning |
| 24 | 93 | বিরাম | viraam | Rest | Rest |
| 30 | 73 | নতিস্বীকার | natiswiikaar | Abnegation | Submission |
| 53 | 34 | কুটুম্বিতা-বিচার | kuTumbitaa-bichaar | Family Feeling | Kinship-consciousness |
| 58 | 6 | ভার | bhaar | The Burden | Glory's Burden |
| 66 | 84 | মোহের আশঙ্কা | moher aasankaa | Captivation's Anxiety | Rapture's Anxiety |
| 71 | 13 | রাষ্ট্রনীতি | raaShtraniiti | Politics | Politics |
| 86 | 79 | ফুল ও ফল | phuul o phal | Flower and Fruit | Flower and Fruit |
| 119 | 106 | চিরনবীনতা | chiranavinataa | Eternal Renewal | Eternal Renewal |
| 129 | 43 | অসম্ভব ভালো | asambhav bhaalo | Impossibly Good | Unbearably Good |
| 130 | 58 | একই পথ | ekii path | The Same Road | The Same Path |
| 134 | 29 | মূল | muul | Roots | Roots |
| 139 | 66 | উপলক্ষ | upalakshya | Synechdoche | One-upmanship |
| 153 | 76 | কর্তব্যগ্রহণ | kartavyagrahaN | Taking Up One's Post | Acceptance of Duty |
| 156 | 64 | মাঝারির সতর্কতা | maajharir satarkataa | The Cautiousness of the Middle | Prudent Mediocrity |
| 157 | 88 | অদৃশ্য কারণ | adR^ishya kaaraN | The Unseen Cause | Invisible Agency |
| 163 | 9 | অসম্পূর্ণ সংবাদ | asampuurNa sa.nvaad | The Unfinished Dialogue | Incomplete Information |
| 166 | 44 | নদীর প্রতি খাল | nadiir prati khaal | The Canal versus the River | Canal's Grievance |
| 172 | 35 | উদারচরিতানাম্‌ | udaaracharitaanaam.h | Greatness of Spirit | Greatness of Spirit |
| 173 | 98 | চালক | chaalak | The Driver | The Driver |
| 176 | 80 | অস্ফুট ও পরিস্ফুট | asphuTa o parisphuTa | The Obscure and the Clear | Shallow and Deep |
| 189 | 10 | ঈর্ষার সন্দেহ | iirShaar sandeha | Jealousy's Suspicions | Jealousy's Suspicions |
| 191 | 82 | স্বাধীনতা | svaadhiinataa | Liberty | Freedom |
| 201 | 30 | হাতে-কলমে | haate-kalame | First-Hand | True Achievement |
| 234 | 63 | নিজের ও সাধারণের | nijer o saadhaaraNer | Private and Public | Public and Private |
| 236 | 86 | পর ও আত্মীয় | par o aatmiya | Alike and Akin | Closer than Kinship |
| 237 | 97 | সুখদুঃখ | sukhadu:kha | Joy and Sorrow | Pleasure and Pain |
| 240 | 45 | স্পর্ধা | spardhaa | The Competition | Arrogance |
| 296 | 85 | স্তুতি নিন্দা | stuti nindaa | Praise and Censure | Praise and Censure |

This table is likely incomplete. I read *kaNikaa* alongside William Radice's translations, then read *Stray Birds*, and tried to connect the sentences in the latter with the poems in the former. I have probably missed some poems, and perhaps misidentified a few as well. Corrections welcomed.

**References**

Tagore, Rabindranath. *[kaNikaa](https://archive.org/details/KanikaRabindranathTagore/mode/2up)*. 1899. Calcutta: Vishwabharati, 1948. Retrieved from the Internet Archive, 11 September 2023.

———. [*Particles, Jottings, Sparks: The Collected Brief Poems*](https://archive.org/details/particlesjotting0000tago/mode/2up). Trans. and Intro. William Radice. London: Angel Books, 2001. Retrieved from the Internet Archive, 11 September 2023.

———. *[Stray Birds](https://www.ibiblio.org/eldritch/rt/stray.htm)*. Translated from Bengali to English by the Author. New York: Macmillan, 1916. Retrieved from ibiblio.org, 11 September 2023.